# How to use Angular expression in Angular Strap's dropdown's href?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu

I am using AngularJS with Angular Strap plugin for one of my projects. On the page I have a table. One of the columns contains some links.

After clicking on the link I pop-ups Angular Strap's dropdown (as contextual menu).

This menu contains two items:

- details,
- board.

Clicking on details item open-ups Angular Strap's aside (with some data to be shown) - this one is working well.

The problem is, the second item should redirects to a specific page (using dropdown's href attribute). My question is - how to use angular expression in this href attribute?

Part of my view's code - with dropdown:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link"
    ng-click="selectGroup(group)"
    data-html="1"
    data-animation="am-flip-x"
    data-placement="bottom",
    bs-dropdown="dropdown">
        {{ group.name }}
</button>
```

Bs-dropdown's dropdown definitions from controller:

```
$scope.dropdown = [
    {
        text: "Details",
        click: "showDetails()" // Opens up Angular Strap's aside.
    },
    {
        text: "Board",
        href: "/group/{{ $scope.group.number }}" // Not evaluated.
    }
];
```

Clicking on "Board" dropdown's item is redirecting to something like: "127.0.0.1:8000/#/group/{{group.number}}" rather than (i.e.) "127.0.0.1:8000/#/group/2".

As a workaround I have created another method (i.e.) openBoard() as follows:

```
var openBoard = function() {
    var groupNumber = $scope.group.number;
    window.location.href="127.0.0.1:8000/#/" + groupNumber;
}
```

Calling this method in "Board" item's click is working, but causes some other problems and more - is not the way I want to go (semantically incorrect).

One more thing at the end. Whenever page loads (and controller has been initialized) value stored in $scope.group is undefined. I am setting a proper value whenever group link (from above mentioned table) is being clicked (and a moment before dropdown is displayed).

Anyone has any ideas how to use Angular expressions with Angular Strap's dropdown (in href)?

Comment: why you don't try `href: "/group/" + $scope.group.number" `.

Comment: Please see the one before last section of above description. As I mentioned - $scope.group at the very beginning is undefined. I tried a similar approach to your with no success (null exceptions). Even with a method like this: 
var groupId = function(group) { 
    if(group === null) return ""; 
    return group.number; 
};
I supposed that, after updating $scope.group the view should be updated (and above method should return a correct value). But it is not working either.

Comment: after group gets assign add second element to dropdown array `{
        text: "Board",
        href: "/group/"+$scope.group.number
    }`

Comment: when you get the value of `group`?

Comment: I haven't even thought about editing my dropdown array until now. So, I ended up with one more method prepareDropdown() which is being executed just after selecting group (and where I am setting proper href attribute) - similar to what You have offered. @pankajparkar shouldn't You add Your commend as an answer? Then, I could mark it as correct.

Comment: I added the answer, kindly do check it thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `$scope.group` member doesn't available at starting while creating dropdown array, that will result `href: "/group/{{ $scope.group.number }}"` this to `href: "/group/undefined"`. So I'd suggest you to initially load dropdown with one value,

```
$scope.dropdown = [
    {
        text: "Details",
        click: "showDetails()" // Opens up Angular Strap's aside.
    }
];
```

& whenever group values gets fetched, do assign the second dropdown option

```
$scope.dropdown.push({
    text: "Board",
    href: "/group/" + $scope.group.number
});
```

Hope this work around would help you, Thanks.

Comment: As push() method will always add another dropdown item (every single click) I just prefer to reinitialize the whole $scope.dropdown array (because I need just two items - and only one "Board" item). But generally, it is a correct answer.

Comment: yes..reintialization would be better way in your case..Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you must change `{{ $scope.group.number }}` for this `/group/group.number`

Comment: Not working. Resolves as "127.0.0.1:8000/#/$scope.group.number".